# Linking to CSS from layouts using Padrino, Sass, and Slim

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sass, padrino, slim-lang

I'm currently using Padrino with Sass and Slim to markup a site that I'm making; however, I'm having trouble linking my CSS (converted from the Sass). My application.slim layout is as follows:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title "test"

        = stylesheet_link_tag "clear"
        script src="/javascripts/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"

body
    div.header
        p.title Hello World
        p.subtitle Subtext Here

    div.content
        == yield

    div.footer
        p.copywrite This is a footer.
```

the view for the page I'm testing on is blank, and renders to the following text:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/clear.css?1342971760" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
Hello World

Subtext Here

This is a footer.
```

The link to "/stylesheets/clear.css" points to the correct place as far as I can tell, but the  tag is being added to the body, instead of the header in which the call is located. In addition, the entire tag is in quotes in the rendered HTML.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing `link href='/stylesheets/clear.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'`, and it seems to work now. I still wish I knew how to make the other method work, but this will do.